# Use Reg Expression to reformat image in RSS feed

Tags: php, regex, rss, preg-replace

I am creating some RSS feeds using PHP (5.2) from a MySQL db specifically for an iPhone app I am making through AppMakr.

They are taken from articles on a website which contain images embedded in them, however in the feeds they don't look great. What I want to try and do is whenever there is an image surround it in `<p>` so they are on their own line and don't try to wrap around article text.

The format of a image is like this:

```
 <a rel="lightbox" href="http://images.domain.comk/543/image1.jpg"><img class="imageright" src="http://images.domain.comk/543/image1.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="250" /></a>
```

So basically surrounded with a `<a href>` and with a class of "imageright" or "imageleft".

What I would love to change this to is:

```
 <p><img src="http://images.domain.comk/543/image1.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="250" /></p>
```

Basically removing the href and imagexxxx class and surrounding in p tags.

I am thinking preg_replace will prob have to be used, but at a loss to what I would actually use for it. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: it is a good idea to take some time to learn more about Regular Expressions. Using example ones can lead to bugs that are hard to fix if you do not understand what the expression is doing.

Comment: If I am reading you correctly, is it not better to figure out how to just store the image url into your database in the rirst place? eg http://images.domain.comk/543/image1.jpg

Comment: Yeah, storing the image URL seperatly is deff the way to go in the future, however I have to cater for a few thousand articles written before this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will need to use a regexp  for matching like this one:

```
<a(.*)><img(.*)class="imageright" (.*)></a>
```

And then a replace regexp like this:

```
<p><img$2$3></p>
```

This is not the most flexible one but it should do the trick for preg_replace()

Comment: Many thanks all, with a combination of help I managed to work out the RegEx needed, I ended up using: `$imagePattern = '/<a.*><img.*src="(.*)" alt.*>/';
$imageReplacement = '<p><img src="$1"></p>';
$intro = preg_replace($imagePattern, $imageReplacement, $intro);`

Answer (score 0):

This Regex matches the opening and closing pair of a specific HTML tag. Anything between the tags is stored into the first capturing group.

```
'<%TAG%[^>]*>(.*?)</%TAG%>'
```

This gives us a starting point. Now we need to replace the `<a href></a>` with `<p></p>`

PHP provides an easy method to do this in preg_replace()

```
preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

now just insert the correct values:

```
$patterns = '<%a%[^>]*>(.*?)</%a%>';
$replacement = '<%p%[^>]*>(.*?)</%p%>';
$text = ' <a rel="lightbox" href="http://images.domain.comk/543/image1.jpg"><img class="imageright" src="http://images.domain.comk/543/image1.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="250" /></a>';

echo preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

This is a non-tested example and is meant to be used as a pattern. You should read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php before creating your solution.